# How to use the auth:api middleware for all Lumen routes?

Tags: laravel, lumen

We have a Lumen installation with the Tymon Jwt -package and it’s working fine when we implement the middleware in the routes file, by using “auth:api” as the middleware name.

However we would like to add that middleware to all routes automatically and only whitelist a couple of routes to skip it. How is it done? Other global middlewares are installed in bootstrap/app.php but we can’t find the correct class to call if we want to use the auth:api -middleware.

I guess it’s quite simple but can’t find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply it to all routes, [use a global middleware](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#global-middleware):

> If you want a middleware to be run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the call to the `$app->middleware()` method in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:
>
> ```
> $app->middleware([
>    App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware::class
> ]);
> ```

`tymon/jwt-auth` provides [several possible `Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware` middleware classes](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/tree/develop/src/Http/Middleware) for your use. Pick the most appropriate to your scenario.

(Your middleware could exempt certain routes internally, in this scenario, probably using something like `Request::is('foo/*')`).

To apply it to most (but not all) routes, put the relevant routes in a route group:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
    // most of your routes go here
});

// the handful of non-auth routes go here
```

Comment: We made our own middleware extending the Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware, which seems to work well. Thanks.